# Meaning of version info in .mod.c file in Linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, kernel, driver

In all loadable kernel modules, when `make` is given it produces a file called `modulename.mod.c` in addition to `modulename.ko`.

Following code excerpt is from a `.mod.c` file, which contains a `{number, function}` pair.
What is the significance of this number? How this number is generated by the compiler?

```
static const struct modversion_info ____versions[]
__used
__attribute__((section("__versions"))) = {

        { 0xa6d8dcb5, "module_layout" },
        { 0x16c2b958, "register_netdevice" },
        { 0x609f1c7e, "synchronize_net" },
        { 0x90a60c63, "kmem_cache_destroy" },
        { 0x402b8281, "__request_module" },
        { 0x844a8af7, "netdev_info" },
        { 0xdfdb0ee8, "kmalloc_caches" },
        { 0x12da5bb2, "__kmalloc" },
        { 0x92d42843, "cfg80211_cqm_rssi_notify" },
        { 0xc86289e8, "perf_tp_event" },
...
...
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `__versions` section contained in all the individual `*.mod.c` files

```
  CRC         Symbol
{ 0xa6d8dcb5, "module_layout" },
{ 0x16c2b958, "register_netdevice" },
  ...         ...
```

is a list of symbols and their corresponding CRCs. This has 2 main uses :

1. Global list of all exported symbols.
2. Module versioning check when loading **`ko`** modules.

---

#### Rationale behind Module versioning

> Module versioning is enabled by the **CONFIG_MODVERSIONS** tag, and is
>   used as a simple ABI consistency check. A CRC value of the full
>   prototype for an exported symbol is created. When a module is
>   loaded/used, the CRC values contained in the kernel are compared with
>   similar values in the module; if they are not equal, the kernel
>   refuses to load the module as it indicates that the module is built with
>   reference to a different version of the Linux kernel source.

Upon successful compilation, The global list of all the CRCs of all the exported symbols is stored in the file `Module.symvers` in the Linux kernel source directory. Essentially this check ensures that any exported symbol that is being called from a kernel module exists in the same location (offset in the kernel) as expected by the module.

The **modpost** tool generates the CRCs during compilation of the Linux Kernel. It is invoked by the [modpost script](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/scripts/Makefile.modpost). The entire process is explained in detail at the [Documentation/kbuild/modules.rst:450](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/kbuild/modules.rst#n450).

The [entire source code of the modpost tool](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/scripts/mod/modpost.c) is available in the Linux kernel source. [**`add_depends()`**](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/scripts/mod/modpost.c#n2344) is the relevant function responsible for generating the entire `__versions` section in each of the `*.mod.c` files.